# What electronic resources are available that categorize nouns by countability?

Tags: nouns, dictionary, countability

Most electronic dictionaries I've found only categorize words into noun / verb / adjective / adverb / etc. (such as WordNet). They don't further refine parts of speech into subcategories like **count/noncount noun** or **transitive/intransitive verb** or **attributive/predicative adjectives**.

What resources are out there that make these refinements? Open source and free resources are preferred.

Comment: Those are properties not of words, but of uses of words in utterances. The same noun can be either count or noncount (e.g, _stone_), the same verb can be either transitive or intransitive (e.g, _open_), and virtually any adjective except _gala_ can be either attributive and predicative. You want those, you gotta parse the syntax to see how they're used; this is not a dictionary-lookup situation.

Comment: @jlawler: is there no information about these categories stored in the lexicon at all? Then how do we explain the ill-formedness of things like *an advice, or *a furniture?

Comment: It's contradictory because different lexicons use different criteria (or none at all -- American dictionaries won't tell you that _a bowl of rice_ is grammatical but **a bowl of bean* is not, for instance). In practice, what NLP people do is use much larger and more specific POS tag sets, with many subtypes specified. Each tag set is usually configured for a tagger/parser system. So the tagger will recognize (with a certain degree of accuracy) transitive from intransitive verbs, count nouns from mass, and attributive from predicative adjectives, in individual sentences.

Comment: jlawler, you're saying that words aren't inherently subcategorized by POS; it's all in how they are used. But isn't it the lexicographer's job to ascertain how the words are commonly used in order to classify them?

Comment: Most words are not like "stone" or "open," which can adopt different senses. "Mankind" cannot be made to fit in a countable context very easily. Neither does "particle" fit within a mass noun context. A good dictionary will categorize a given noun as either count, noncount, or both.

I'll grant that most adjectives can be used both attributively and predicatively, but there are a few notable exceptions such as "afraid" or "ajar" which can only be used predicatively and "mere" or "former" which only function correctly as attributes.

Comment: No, the lexicographer's job is not to do grammar, but to do the lexicon. Grammar is a separate phenomenon, consisting of the patterns in which lexical units may be arrayed. Dictionaries don't cover this; they can't. [Here's a list of English syntax rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf); what dictionary would have anything to say about them?

Comment: Is it incorrect for dictionaries even to categorize words as nouns and verbs, then?

Comment: They do what they can. Generally nouns and verbs have different definitions, so it's reasonable to provide them in a dictionary. But there are way too many possible patterns they can be used in. Here's an analogy: from identifying all the atoms in an organic molecule -- 2 C, 6 H, 1 O -- can you tell how it will affect the human body? There are known rules (and quite a few unknown ones) for combining these elements, and the elements are identified. Would you expect the periodic table to contain the information that some ways of arranging these atoms will get you drunk?

Comment: So you're saying no such resource exists, then? (re: my original question)